# List files in a datalake using sas url in Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

How to list files in a datalake directory ? I used the following code to get the same but was getting an error.I created the sasurl from azure storage explorer with read and list permissions

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

sas_url = "https://<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<dir_name>/<dir_path>?sv=2020-02-10&st=2023-03-30T06%3A39%3A45Z&se=2023-03-31T06%3A39%3A45Z&sr=d&sp=rl&sig=xxD&sdd=3"
filesystem_name = 'filesystem_name'
directory_path = '/directory_path/'
storage_account_name = 'storage_account_name'
account_url=f"https://<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net"


datalake_service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url=sas_url, logging_enable=True)
file_client = datalake_service_client.get_file_system_client(filesystem_name)
paths = file_system_client.get_paths(directory_path)
for path in paths:
    print(path)
```

But at for path in paths, it's throwing an error as follows:

```
HttpResponseError: (InvalidQueryParameterValue) Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
RequestId:c2ac7695-d01f-0030-4df1-6212f2000000
Time:2023-03-30T10:22:26.0744702Z
Code: InvalidQueryParameterValue
Message: Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
RequestId:c2ac7695-d01f-0030-4df1-6212f2000000
Time:2023-03-30T10:22:26.0744702Z
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering suggests that there is an issue with one of the query parameters specified in the SAS URL that you are using to authenticate your access to the data lake. Specifically, it seems that one of the query parameters has an invalid value.

You may want to double-check the SAS URL and ensure that all the query parameters have the correct values. For example, you may want to verify that the "st" (start time) and "se" (expiry time) parameters have valid date and time values.

In addition, in the code you provided, you are using sas_url as the account_url parameter when creating the DataLakeServiceClient. You should set account_url to the URL of your data lake account, not the SAS URL.

Comment: I created it from azure storage explorer with read and list permissions.